# Linux networking forces browsers to crash across all distros

Tags: linux, networking, browser

I am really starting to think this is a MB issue seeing as I replicate the problem with all distros, all browsers and using USB and PCI wireless and ethernet cable.

The net connection behaves very oddly. All browsers crash on trying to load a web page 9/10 times. once connected to a stream or a download they run without stopping but normal browsing is unusable.

I honestly don't know what to do. I have gone through every guide and every forum thread. Pulling my hair out here.

Can anyone help?

EDIT:

Using Chromium I get this repeatedly in terminal:

```
(npviewer.bin:6272): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Comment: If you have strange crashes like that, my first step would be to grab the livecd image http://www.memtest.org/ and check your RAM.  It might be more related to the fact that many browsers are memory hogs and they're finding themselves using faulty RAM. Does the box seem to work otherwise?

Comment: Everything else works, including games, DAW and other memory heavy applications. But I'll check nevertheless. Thanks!

Comment: Can you say exactly what you mean by "crash"?  When you say "crash on trying to load a web page 9/10 times", do you mean that the crash occurs approximately once in every 10 attempts, or that the crash occurs approximately 9 times in every 10 attempts?

Comment: Nine times out of every ten the browser crashes. Firefox and Opera close totally, Chromium shuts the page process down.